# Several errors per minute: "Failed to start Tracker file system data miner." and "Failed to start Tracker metadata extractor."

Tags: gnome, tracker

I installed Ubuntu 21.10 Desktop from a Live USB over the weekend to a NAS device. Performance was abysmal but I kept at it and eventually screwed something up, unable to boot after a day. So I reinstalled (without formatting from scratch -- I had already moved 3TB of data back onto the drives and didn't want to do it again) and everything is working as expected, performance is better... But when I check logs via Cockpit, I'm seeing a couple of consistent errors showing up, several times per minute:

```
 - "Failed to start Tracker file system data miner." *(happens consistently 6 times per minute)*
 - "Failed to start Tracker metadata extractor." *(consistently 4 times per minute)*
```

According to logs, these errors began approximately 20 minutes after the OS was installed and fully booted.

Now, obviously this seems related to Tracker3. But I'm not sure it's caused by it, because I followed [steps from this blog](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/how-to-completely-disable-tracker.html) to disable tracker3 completely, rebooted, and the errors persist.

**What else I've tried:**

- Attempted to reset tracker database via tracker reset -r -s
- I read that tracker can be thrown off by broken files, so I cleaned out, to the best of my ability, the Photos/Movies/Documents/Downloads/etc. folders. They were mostly empty anyway.
- Went to Settings > Search > disabled Search

If I query tracker for its status, this is what it reports:

```
Currently indexed: 129 files, 15 folders  
Remaining space on database partition: 2.8 TB (94.28%)  
All data miners are idle, indexing complete
```

**Here is the output from Cockpit when I click on the "Failed to start Tracker file system data miner" error:**

```
systemd  
Failed to start Tracker file system data miner.  
CODE_FILE   src/core/job.c  
CODE_FUNC   job_log_done_status_message  
CODE_LINE   938  
JOB_ID  55426  
JOB_RESULT  failed  
JOB_TYPE    start  
MESSAGE_ID  be02cf6855d2428ba40df7e9d022f03d  
PRIORITY    3  
SYSLOG_FACILITY 3  
SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER   systemd  
TID 1708  
USER_INVOCATION_ID  058f1e0ef4644facb9fe004971d0990a  
USER_UNIT   tracker-miner-fs-3.service 
_AUDIT_LOGINUID 998  
_AUDIT_SESSION  5  
_BOOT_ID    a9c239348bf4402da3c932c95d34900c  
_CAP_EFFECTIVE  0  
_CMDLINE    /lib/systemd/systemd --user  
_COMM   systemd  
_EXE    /usr/lib/systemd/systemd  
_GID    998  
_HOSTNAME   NetworkStorage  
_MACHINE_ID f6292d361b38446b809654d2a4f3ff0d  
_PID    1708  
_SELINUX_CONTEXT    unconfined  
_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP  1646323317230382  
_SYSTEMD_CGROUP /user.slice/user-998.slice/user@998.service/init.scope  
_SYSTEMD_OWNER_UID  998  
_SYSTEMD_SLICE  user-998.slice  
_SYSTEMD_UNIT   user@998.service  
_SYSTEMD_USER_SLICE -.slice  
_SYSTEMD_USER_UNIT  init.scope  
_TRANSPORT  journal 
_UID    998  
__CURSOR    s=1225d662430a48c482616e099954af45;i=4b439;b=a9c239348bf4402da3c932c95d34900c;  m=84cf21c53;t=5d95284827354;x=e8dce6118371f266  
__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP   35650673747  
__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP    1646323317240660
```

**And here's the output for the "Failed to start Tracker metadata extractor." error:**

```
systemd  
Failed to start Tracker metadata extractor.  
CODE_FILE   src/core/job.c  
CODE_FUNC   job_log_done_status_message  
CODE_LINE   938  
JOB_ID  61088  
JOB_RESULT  failed  
JOB_TYPE    start  
MESSAGE_ID  be02cf6855d2428ba40df7e9d022f03d  
PRIORITY    3  
SYSLOG_FACILITY 3  
SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER   systemd  
TID 1708  
USER_INVOCATION_ID  4a4a35f756d841659a948cb6e08ea36d  
USER_UNIT   tracker-extract-3.service  
_AUDIT_LOGINUID 998  
_AUDIT_SESSION  5  
_BOOT_ID    a9c239348bf4402da3c932c95d34900c  
_CAP_EFFECTIVE  0  
_CMDLINE    /lib/systemd/systemd --user  
_COMM   systemd  
_EXE    /usr/lib/systemd/systemd  
_GID    998  
_HOSTNAME   NetworkStorage  
_MACHINE_ID f6292d361b38446b809654d2a4f3ff0d  
_PID    1708  
_SELINUX_CONTEXT    unconfined  
_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP  1646326944495198  
_SYSTEMD_CGROUP /user.slice/user-998.slice/user@998.service/init.scope  
_SYSTEMD_OWNER_UID  998  
_SYSTEMD_SLICE  user-998.slice  
_SYSTEMD_UNIT   user@998.service  
_SYSTEMD_USER_SLICE -.slice  
_SYSTEMD_USER_UNIT  init.scope  
_TRANSPORT  journal  
_UID    998  
__CURSOR    s=1225d662430a48c482616e099954af45;i=4c1ae;b=a9c239348bf4402da3c932c95d34900c;  m=92525d7ee;t=5d9535cb62eee;x=364e9a55bd789d06  
__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP   39277942766  
__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP    1646326944509678
```

For what it's worth, my install is stock except for the following software (and dependencies):

- Plex Media Server
- Plex Media Player
- Pi-Hole
- Steam
- Steam Link
- xone (xbox gamepad driver)
- Cockpit

Not sure where to attempt to troubleshoot next, so would love some suggestions.